# How to reenter a snippet in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, code-snippets

After editing the snippet partially, I click outside of the snippet and lose focus of the snippet. when I reinsert my cursor in the snippet I no longer can tab through the preset tab locations.

I found in a previous post that "option + shift + tab" worked for reentering a snippet on mac (not sure if it is true), how is this done on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does nothing on the Mac.

`Shift` + `Tab` allows you to go backwards in a snippet, but as soon as you unfocus the snippet you have lost the tabbing.

Comment: I knew about the shift tab. so sad that this doesn't exist. thanks. I'll hold out a bit longer just in case someone can enlighten us before I award you the answer.